# How to check if Username exists in specific column of database

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm using C# with an ASP.Net table. I'm trying to check when a user accesses my web app, that their User ID is listed in the column called `UserID` in a table that is displayed in the web app. If it is not, then I want to redirect them to an error page.

I need this to check when the page is loaded so obviously it needs to be in `Page_Load`. I just don't know how to call the column in my table and to have it check the User ID.

This is what I have so far:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{            
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        string UserID = HttpContext.Current.Request.LogonUserIdentity.Name.Substring(4);
        SQLUserID();

        if (UserID != //'Whatever values are in the UserID column'//)
        {
            Server.Transfer("ErrorPage.aspx");
        }

        SQLCmd = SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
}
```

The string `UserID` gives me the User ID of the user. `SQLUserID() = SELECT UserId FROM Info.` I know the way I called that isn't correct but I'm not sure how to do it.

Comment: You should definitely load up entity framework. Are you using .net core or .net 4x?

Comment: Honestly I don't know what that means but I think I'm on .net Core

Comment: @derekg8881, you are not using .Net core. You can check from the properties tab of that project. This is most probably some version of .Net framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here is how I got it to work below `Page_Load`

```
{
string connectionString = "Data Source=###;Initial Catalog=###;Integrated Security=True";
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)                
        {
            using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                sqlConnection.Open();

                using (SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(UserID) from Info WHERE UserID like @UserID", sqlConnection))
                {
                    string UserID = HttpContext.Current.Request.LogonUserIdentity.Name.Substring(4);                        
                    sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserID", UserID);
                    int userCount = (int)sqlCommand.ExecuteScalar();
                    if (userCount == 0)
                    {
                        Server.Transfer("ErrorPage.aspx");
                    }

                    SQLCmd = SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand;
                    GridView1.DataBind();
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

It can help you:

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString); 
SqlCommand check_User_Name ("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tblUser WHERE (UserID=@UserID)",conn);
check_User_Name.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserID,UserID);
int userExist=(int)check_User_Name.ExecuteScalar();
if(userExist>0)
{
    //Login
}
else
{
   Server.Transfer("ErrorPage.aspx");
}
```

just write your connection string and enjoy it.

Comment: What is check_User_Name?

Comment: I edit it.Thank you.It is an object with the type of SqlCommand.

Comment: This thing is just riddled with errors when I put it in `if (!Page.IsPostBack)`